# Convert number into character

Tags: c++

I want an reverse integer value.

the code

```
int number = 123, num1, num2, num3;
num1 = number / 100;
num2 = number % 100 / 10;
num3 = number % 10;

static_cast<char>(num1, num2, num3);

cout << num3 + num2 + num1 << endl;
```

**the result is 6..** (I wanted '321' to come out.)

what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Why do you think `num3 + num2 + num1` (3 + 2 + 1) wouldn't be 6? Also `static_cast<char>(num1, num2, num3);` using the comma operator is almost definitely not doing what you expect.

Comment: `static_cast` returns the result, it doesn't change the argument. Also C++ is statically typed: if `num1` is an `int`, it forever remains an `int`.

Comment: Why not `cout << (char)(num3 + '0') << (char)(num2 + '0') ...`

Comment: Remember all the divisions you made when isolating the digits? You've got to undo those.

Comment: Convert the number to a string.  Print the string in reverse order or reverse the string, then print the string.

Comment: https://ideone.com/G6GA0Y

Comment: your result was 6, because 6 == 1+2+3, but you wanted to concatenate strings not to add numbers. Use operator << to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

Even if you transform an `int` to a `char` using `static_cast<char>`, it will keep its value. Additionally, that's not the way you call `static_cast<char>`.

### Solution:

If you just want to print them using your method, you don't even have to convert the numbers to `char`. Just print them taking advantage of the `<<` operator.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int number = 123, num1, num2, num3;
    num1 = number / 100;
    num2 = number % 100 / 10;
    num3 = number % 10;
    std::cout << num3 << num2 << num1 << std::endl;
}
```

However, this is will only work for numbers between 100 and 999.

A much better solution would be to transform the number to the `std::string` and reverse it with `std::reverse` from the `<algorithm>` header.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int number = 123;
    std::string str = std::to_string(number);
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Then, if you want to get the reversed number as an integer instead of printing it, you can use `std::stoi`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int number = 123;
    std::string str = std::to_string(number);
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    int reversed_number = std::stoi(str);
    std::cout << reversed_number << std::endl;
}
```

Note that this won't work and will throw an exception for negative numbers because of the leading '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong operator ! Instead of "+" : use "<<" to output concatenation of the 3 integers-strings
No static casting.needed

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv [])
{
  int number = 123, num1, num2, num3;
  num1 = number / 100;
  num2 = number % 100 / 10;
  num3 = number % 10;
  //static_cast<char>(num1, num2, num3);
  std::cout << num3 << num2 << num1 << std::endl;
}
```